# Can't install grunt-cli but can install bower

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gruntjs

I have a linux box behind a no auth proxy.

I have configured git to use https instead of git.

```
url.https://.insteadof=git://
```

I have set my http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables and also the npm proxy.

```
; cli configs
user-agent = "npm/3.8.6 node/v6.0.0 linux x64"

; userconfig /jenkins/.npmrc
https-proxy = "{host}:8060"
proxy = "{host}:8060"
```

I can install bower with:

```
npm install -g bower
```

but when i try

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

i get:

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli/-/grunt-cli-1.2.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL 0.0.31.124:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
....
npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL 0.0.31.124:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
```

I have tried with npm version
3.8.6 / 2.15.1

Any ideas why i can install bower and not grunt-cli from same account in same session (i can even install grunt globally, and clone grunt-cli)?

***UPDATES***

1: I am able to do

```
curl -O https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-cli/-/grunt-cli-1.2.0.tgz
```

with success, the npm https-proxy is equal to $https_proxy value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was my npm proxy was host:port, without the "http://" prefix. like the environment variable.  works now.

I have no idea why bower installed though.

Comment: I had the same problem and it helped me, thanks. I guess you can select your own answer as the best answer :)

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

this looks like a network problem with your proxy configuration.

Update to the latest version of node and npm, and use the correct proxy settings.

Comment: hey, i mis copied and pasted somehow, thanks for showing me that.  that command is what i'm trying to do, i updated my question.